# TeeChart Scroller Cause RedCross Error if Direct2D is set as Graphics3D

Tags: scroll, pager, teechart, direct2d, graphics3d

I am trying TeeChart .Net componets and I am focusing on financial charts.
When I try to use a PageScroller tool to manage chart scrolling, it work well in GDI but cause a Red cross when i set D2D render.

Does somebody know if it is a known issue or i am doing something wrong in this code?

here is how i add the Pager:

```
public teeChartTestCtl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        tool = new Steema.TeeChart.Tools.ScrollPager(tChart1.Chart);
        black.Apply(tool.SubChartTChart.Chart);

        tChart1.Aspect.View3D = false;

        seriesMain.Clear();                       

        for (int i = 0; i < frmMain.tradingClient.chartData.Count; i++)
            {
                BarData bar = frmMain.tradingClient.chartData[i];
                seriesMain.Add(bar.Date, bar.Open,bar.High,bar.Low,bar.Close);
            }

        clonedSeries.DataSource = seriesMain;
        tool.Series = clonedSeries;
        tool.DivisionRatio = 6;

    }
```

Here is how i set D2D Drawing (it work fine if no pager is on the chart)

```
 tChart1.Graphics3D = new Graphics3DDirect2D(tChart1.Chart);
```

Bests,
Salvatore Rossitto.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delay. I have been doing many test with ScrollPager Tool in  TeeChart2D2 and we found that is produced an exception. We have added it in bug list report with number [**TD29016423**] and we will try to fixed it to upcoming versions of TeeChartFor.Net.

Thanks,

Comment: Hello, I wonder if you fixed the issue. I tried the new demo but it seems to have the same problem. I also notice the same problem using OpenGL rendering with the same scroll tool. Bests, Salvatore Rossitto.

Comment: Hello @user1830791, many thanks, I have added your extra information in bug number TD29016423.